# Are indoor rated load centers acceptable for barn subpanel?

Tags: electrical-panel, code-compliance

In a new barn, intended to be a shop, I wish to install a subpanel fed from the house main panel.  My question is whether a normal indoor panel box (load center) can be used.

In ag buildings there seem to be concerns about dirty and also corrosive environments. The use of this building should be neither.  I am wondering if the panel box can be a normal indoor one?

The jurisdiction is US-NY.

Comment: ...are ya putting a roof on it? WIll it be dry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the structure, a normal indoor panel will be acceptable. There are really no panels made for the dust of a working barn; normal snap closed doors on the face are the normal protection. I have enclosed panels with a cabinet door and inspectors usually want the door to have wording like "service panel behind this door" on it. Some require the voltage. In one case, a printed photo of the service panel on the door was acceptable to the inspector.

So, a normal surface mount or inset panel with a dead face and door are all that is required on a panel in a normally dry location.

Comment: Key is the last phrase "normally dry location". AIUI, the key difference between "indoor" and "outdoor" when it comes to electrical is "water".

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to go to a commercial panelboard to get something like a NEMA 12 that'd be considered "dusttight"